# iOS: Simulate drag events on seek bar when playing a movie

Tags: ios, events, media-player

is it possible to simulate drag events on seek bar when playing a movie?
I'm using MPMoviePlayerController to play movies, whose default seek bar can be dragged so that it can seek around. I just want simulate this drag event and send to the seek bar, programmatically. Is there any suggestions? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your want to customize the player, you should use AVPlayer instead. With my experience the AVPlayer is more flexible and better performance than MPMoviePlayerController.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/AVPlayerDemo/Introduction/Intro.html